# OpenMP not spawning additional threads

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm new to OpenMP and cannot for the life of me utilise multiple threads. I have my environment variable set. Here is a snippet of code which simply should just iterate through the mandelbrot set:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <limits>

#define WIDTH 10000
#define HEIGHT 10000
#define INFINITY 2.0f
#define ITERATIONS 1000

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t py = 0; py < HEIGHT; py++) {
        for (size_t px = 0; px < WIDTH; px++) {

            float x0 = -2.5f + (px * (1.0f - -2.5f) / WIDTH);
            float y0 = 1.0f + (py * (-1.0f - 1.0f) / HEIGHT);

            unsigned short iteration;
            float x = 0.0f;
            float y = 0.0f;
            for (iteration = 0; iteration < ITERATIONS; iteration++) {
                float xn = x * x - y * y + x0;
                y = 2 * x * y + y0;
                x = xn;
                if (x * x + y * y > INFINITY) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this, it never spawns additional threads. I feel I'm doing something horribly wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you're using VisualStudio, you need to enable OpenMP in your project preferences, C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support, set to true. If you're using GCC/Clang on Linuxm you need to use appropriate flags when compiling.

Comment: how do you know that no threads are spawned? You `main` actually seems to do nothing that is observable output

Comment: In other words, your entire code is effectively equivalent to `int main(){}`. For instance, GCC under optimizations creates a parallel section, but runs a do-nothing function within: https://godbolt.org/z/1vP9rTM3G.

Comment: turns out i didnt add the compiler flag -fopenmp! i feel like such a moron. now im just getting problems with what i presume are private and shared variables. What I posted above was just a quick abstraction of code online which should have worked but didn't.

Answer (score 3):

I needed at add the flag `-fopenmp` to my compiler arguments. Now works properly.

Comment: You should always use `-Wall` flag to avoid such a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the missing `-fopenmp` flag, OpenMP supports different work scheduling modes and the simple equal work distribution may not reach high efficiency on the run-time minimization for unbalanced workloads like Mandelbrot-Set generation.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for(...){}
```

can be faster for unknown work-intensity per pixel with speedup depending on the unbalance between pixels.